# Does ATS automatically change for seasons?

Tags: american-truck-simulator

I guess not. If it did, why you need mods like [EARLY AUTUMN/FALL V1.3 MOD](http://www.modsats.com/early-autumn-fall-v1-3-mod/) and [Frosty Winter Weather Mod v2.7 ATS](http://www.modsats.com/frosty-winter-weather-mod-v2-7-ats/)?

In real life, I love peeping leaves fall foliage with family. Must I install these Mods every season?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Does ATS automatically change for seasons? : trucksim](https://old.reddit.com/r/trucksim/comments/efm5s0/does_ats_automatically_change_for_seasons/)

> There is no seasons in ats. You have to manually add in mods

[Does ATS automatically change for seasons? : trucksim](https://old.reddit.com/r/trucksim/comments/efm5s0/does_ats_automatically_change_for_seasons/)

> Proper season implementation requires a lot of work and will most probably bloat the game size. Not only it would require a lot of extra textures but also to adjust for differences between locations which now isn’t doable in the game. Even seasonal mods have to apply the same textures everywhere even if in some places it is unrealistic.

Answer (score 1):

There's no support for it in the vanilla game but there's some great mods for it. Note: might not be available in Steam workshop - you can get them here https://grimesmods.wordpress.com/category/ats-mods/. Also got the awesome "Real Companies" mod.

Be aware that these often need to be updated whenever a patch/new DLC map comes out though. If you experience weird stuff like no other trucks visible in the game suddenly, an old version of these mods is very likely the cause. So far the maintainer has been doing a good job of keeping them up to date in a somewhat timely manner though.